# HTTP protocol connectionless and use TCP by default, How does that make sense?

Tags: http, web, tcp

I read that HTTP protocol uses the reliable TCP connections by default
,and one of the HTTP feature is connectionless.
Now I am confused how does it make sense ?
How does it use TCP and the same time it is connectionless and as I know TCP is connection-oriented

Comment: connectionless means that for every new request, we need to create a new connection from the client to the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP and TCP are different things. [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is a transport layer protocol, whereas [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is an application layer protocol. HTTP uses TCP for data transmissions.

IMO [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_overview.htm) website has a nice explanation:

> **HTTP is connectionless:** The HTTP client, i.e., a browser initiates an HTTP request and after a request is made, the client waits for the response. The server processes the request and sends a response back after which client disconnect the connection. So client and server knows about each other during current request and response only. Further requests are made on new connection like client and server are new to each other.

However, Wikipedia defines HTTP as stateless:

> HTTP is a stateless protocol. A stateless protocol does not require the HTTP server to retain information or status about each user for the duration of multiple requests. However, some web applications implement states or server side sessions using for instance HTTP cookies or hidden variables within web forms.

Based on their explanations, the terms seems to be used interchangeably. However, these are not really true as the in-use HTTP versions allow you to identify the users through cookies etc. and create [persistent](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2#one_connection_per_origin) connections.

Comment: Okay that's great, so because the HTTP is connectionless thant means it is like UDP right ?
how in the application layer it is connectionless and in transport layer uses connection-oriented , that is what makes me confused about HTTP ?
could you make it more clear ?

Comment: No, by connectionless it is meant that the HTTP server and client does not recognize each other outside the request, and once the transfer is complete they forget everything. This is more like a definition for recognition/remembrance situation rather than network. E.g. client requests a file from the server, the server says "ok, who are you and what do you want?", then gives the client what it wanted and the network connection gets closed and the server and the client forget about each other. When the same clients asks for some other file to the same server the server again asks "who are you?"

Comment: Another example would be when you call a customer services. You have the phone line open and connected when you call them and you close your phone call when you have finished. And each time you call them (i.e. create a connection) they ask for your name and what do you want.

Comment: Well, cool, why does HTTP use TCP and not UDP?
Could me you provide like this explanation with an example?

Comment: TCP is more reliable than UDP. TCP creates a connection and ensures that your data packages arrive at the same order you send. On the other hand, UDP does not create a connection, never guarantees your packages will arrive, and may get your packages lost on the way and you wouldn't even know about it. However, now there's HTTP/3 that uses the QUIC protocol, which internally uses UDP, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3).

Comment: @tugrul What you mean by the second comment is the defination for stateless protocol and not connectionless.